# how can I connect my react js app to firebase 9?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been practicing on this react js app and wanted to connect to firebase for authentication of account creating and signing. but I get this error message,

Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package /Users/feysel/roum/node_modules/firebase (see exports field in /Users/feysel/roum/node_modules/firebase/package.json). and I couldn't find the fix.

this is the firebase.js code
`

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAXdZmTDJjxY1cxn2QkNaqh2FzbGDPjds8",
  authDomain: "roum-34c72.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "roum-34c72",
  storageBucket: "roum-34c72.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "509648148482",
  appId: "1:509648148482:web:6d66ae1678c1ddfd3baf1b",
  measurementId: "G-Z9EK18CBH0",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

`and this one is from login.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Login.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "./firebase";

function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  const register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((auth) => {
        //new user creation successful with username & password
        console.log(auth);
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
```

`

Comment: Since you mention v9, did you try following the documentation on how to initialize Firebase? https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: yeah, after posting this question I have been going through the documentation and tried to implement it but no new thing. It still says firebaseApp is not defined.